# Почему кастомный шрифт типа ttf не подключается?

Tags: шрифты, css

Почему увстомный шрифт типа ttf не подключается? Когда использую woff - подключение идет. А в случае с ttf - ничего не меняется. В чем причина?

Comment: какой шрифт - название

Comment: Caecilia @soledar10

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите как идет подключение шрифта. Должно быть что-то подобное:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Caecilia';
    src: url('Caecilia.eot');
    src: url('Caecilia.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Caecilia.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Caecilia.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Caecilia.svg#webfontZam02nTh') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

Название, стиль и жирность указываете в соответствии с тем шрифтом который подключаете.

Comment: я писал то же самое. Не работает

Comment: Загрузите пример куда-нибудь. Можно на http://rghost.ru

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться конвертером шрифтов и подключите новые, сконвертированные.
[Ссылка на конвертер](http://www.freefontconverter.com)